# LaTeX equation that has white text on a transparent background

Tags: equations, color, backgrounds, transparency

I would like to create a LaTeX equation that has white text on a transparent background, so that I can use it on an array of dark backgrounds in PowerPoint/Keynote.

```
\color{white}
\nopagecolor
\begin{equation}
 V_{\rm eff}(k) = \int d^3r \; \left [ n( { \bm{r} })P(k) \over  1+n(\bm{r})P(k)\right]^2
\end{equation}
```

But doesn't work. 
Any thoughts?

Comment: Please note that two letter font commands, such as `\rm` are deprecated and should no longer be used.

Answer (score 7):

With the `standalone` documentclass one can create a document which just contains an equation and (in case PP/keynote cannot directly import a pdf) convert it into a `.png` with transparent background:

```
\documentclass[margin=6.626mm,convert]{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\color{white}
$\displaystyle
M87 = \mathrm{cool}
$
\end{document}
```

(needs to be compiled with `shell-escape` enabled)

> [image]
>   <- Hard to see here, but this produces an image with transparent background and white font

Comment: Why is it necessary to compile with shell-escape?

Comment: @Lupino Because the `convert` option uses an external program to convert the resulting pdf to png. To allow this the `shell-escape` option has to be used.